# Normalize data according to business entity (Legal name, class of business, DNS domain, company type)

Tags: web-services, normalization, wolframalpha

I'm trying to normalize data and link records according to legal business entity name.

Where can I determine the legal business name, and general information about that company?  I will have at least one of the following: Stock symbol, DBA (short name), dns name, or full legal name.

So far I've discovered that with the

- Relying on whois gives me private, or out of date information
- Wolfram Alpha API gives me most of what I need for [public companies](http://api.wolframalpha.com/v2/query?input=nfp.com&appid=7PTJH4-P8P6TJEU7U&includepodid=CorporateInformationPod%3aInternetData&includepodid=HostInformationPod%3aInternetData) but nothing helpful for [private](http://api.wolframalpha.com/v2/query?input=lego.com&appid=7PTJH4-P8P6TJEU7U&includepodid=CorporateInformationPod%3aInternetData&includepodid=HostInformationPod%3aInternetData) companies like LEGO
- Parsing webpages for the (c) symbol may help in the resolution process, but doesn't match a name to an authoritative list.

Since all stock symbols are categorized; that one is easy.

How can I convert, normalize, and verify DBA (short name), dns name, or full legal name for non-public or non profit businesses that may even be located overseas?

(e.g. MET Museum as DBA, or metmuseum.org as site, or "Metropolitan Museum of Art" Legal name)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that people interested in database-normalization would consider this question far off-topic. (That's an observation, not a criticism.) I'm aware that "normalization" is used in a lot of different contexts with different meanings on SO, so I'm going to leave that tag in place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this is the best place to ask your question. Maybe your local librarian could help. Anyway, I'm answering because I've done a lot of work along these lines in the past, and because I've found that programmers and database designers often know where to find data--especially authoritative and standard data.

At the local level (in the USA), we accepted whatever the local Chamber of Commerce gave us. At the national level, we bought lists from [InfoUSA](http://www.infousa.com/). Chamber of Commerce data can be pretty flaky; InfoUSA data is very clean.

[Dun & Bradstreet](http://www.dnb.com/) is the closest I know of to a one-stop global business registry. They're not cheap.

[RBA](http://www.rba.co.uk/sources/registers.htm), a company in the UK, seems to have a really useful introduction with a global perspective. See [Official Company Registers](http://www.rba.co.uk/sources/registers.htm). Much of the data there is free.

Answer (score 1):

I have been doing some research in this area and found a recent paper which discusses an approach to extract, discover (via clustering) and normalize (by an enhanced edit-distance calculation) organization names. [NEMO](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2990275/?report=classic)